# Jupiter Labs Syntax Error when building out perceptron

Tags: jupyter-lab

Working on building out a perceptron and I'm having issues defining a function and being able to call it...yet 5 minutes earlier it worked and now it doesn't?

```
def draw(x1,x2): 
    ln = plt.plot(x1, x2)

def sigmoid(score):
    return 1/(1+ np.exp(-score))

def calculate_error(line_parameters, points, y): 
    m = points.shape[0]
    p = sigmoid(points*line_parameters
    cross_entropy = -(1/m)*(np.log(p).T * y + np.log(1-p).T*(1-y))
    return cross_entropy
```

[image]

Comment: Paste your code instead of image so that we can compile it.

Comment: Please check out the revised code

Comment: What is the token directly preceding the occurrence of `cross_entropy` indicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a closed parenthesis in the `calculate_error` def. Change:

```
p = sigmoid(points*line_parameters
```

with

```
p = sigmoid(points*line_parameters)
```